# notepad++ regex insert value inbetween pattern

Tags: regex

I need a regex matcher to find the pattern for a list consisting of a bunch of records

all of which end with a comma.

I want to, at the first occurrence of the comma insert beginning and end h1 tags.

I tried using (.*),

Comment: Can we see a sample input and output list?

Comment: Random Text In One Row, <- this is how every line looks. ends with a comma

Comment: Just tried in notepad++, your regex works, did you enable the regex search in the bottom-left corner of the search box?

Comment: can you provide exactly what regex you used? (.*), <- ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should capture everything on a line up until and including the comma:

```
[^,]*?,
```

Comment: But hey what if I want to end the line after the first occurrence of the comma? Because there are more commas on the same line, and I dont want them to be altered

Comment: This will depend on the regex implementation that you are using. The regex here by itself will start the the beginning of a string and match everything up tp and including the first comma.  So long as your regex function does not globally match all occurrences, this will ignore all other comma-delimited text on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Try using either `(.*?),` or `([^,]+),`.  The former is preferred, but Notepad++ may not support it.

Comment: But this only locates the comma... I need to locate the string before the comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^([^,]*),
```

This will locate the string before the first comma in a line. There is also capturing group that captures the text before the first comma for reference in replacement.